# Jquery Custom Modal Plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a modal plugin using jQuery. It works fine if I have to call one modal only but when there is more that on modal in the page, both the modal's get called or sometimes only one if try to change the code. I want to target the modal which has the same id on click. Don't know what's wrong with the code, help would be really appreciated. The code goes as below.

You can check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/A9AtV/

Here is the code

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#333;
}
h1 {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#dd7e2a;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
form, button {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
article {
    padding:10px;
}
.modal {
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid #dd7e2a;
    width:600px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
}
.controls {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
}
.controls label {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.close {
    position:absolute;
    right:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px solid #dd7e2a;
    color:#333;
    font-size:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.backdrop {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(47, 175, 102, 0.8);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
form button, .contact {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    outline:none;
    border:3px solid #dd7e2a;
    line-height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:0 10px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    color:#dd7e2a;
    max-width:100px;
}
form button:hover, .contact:hover {
    border-color:rgba(47, 175, 102, 0.8);
    color:rgba(47, 175, 102, 0.8);
}
form {
    padding:20px;
}
body form textarea {
    height:50px;
}
body form button {
    margin:0;
}
form input, form textarea {
    border:2px solid #dd7e2a;
    height:25px;
    width:300px;
    transition:all 0.6s ease;
    color:#dd7e2a;
    outline:none;
}
form input:focus, form textarea:focus {
    border-color:rgba(47, 175, 102, 0.8);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="contactme" data-width="400" data-toggle="modal" class="modal">
    <form>
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="contactyou" data-width="400" data-toggle="modal" class="modal">
    <form>
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<a href="#" data-target="contactme" class="contact">First Button</a><br>
<a href="#" data-target="contactyou" class="contact">Second Button</a>
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
    var someglobal = $('.modal');

    // Modal Functinonality
    var contactform = {
        container: $(someglobal),
        config: {
            effect: 'slideToggle',
            speed: 500,
        },
        // Initial Function
        init: function (config) {
            $.extend(this.config, config);
            var id = $('.modal').attr('id');
            var newv = $('a').data('target');

            sv = $('a').data('target');
            $('a[data-target]').on('click', this.show);

            function modal() {
                var wid = $('div').data('width');
                cont = $(someglobal)
                wid = $(cont).css({
                    'width': wid + 'px',
                });

                wid = $(cont).css({
                    'left': ($(window).width() - $(cont).width()) / 2 + 'px',
                        'top': ($(window).height() - $(cont).height()) / 2 + 'px'
                });
            }

            // Adding modal on resize and dom ready
            $(document).ready(modal);
            $(window).resize(modal);

            console.log(someglobal.attr('id'));
        },
        // Show Function
        show: function () {
            var cf = contactform,
                //container = cf.container,
                config = cf.config
                $new = $(this).data('target'),
                console.log(someglobal);

            if (sv == $(someglobal).attr("id")) {
                cf.close.call(someglobal);
                cf.fadediv.call(someglobal);
                someglobal[config.effect](config.speed);
            }
        },

        // Close function   
        close: function () {
            var $this = $(this);            
            if ($this.find('span.close').length) return;

            $('<span class=close>x</span>')
                .prependTo(this)
                .on('click', function () {
                $this[contactform.config.effect](contactform.config.speed);
                $('body').find('div.backdrop').fadeOut(300);
            })
        },
        // Backdrop Fade div    
        fadediv: function () {
            $('<div></div>', {
                class: 'backdrop'
            })
                .appendTo('body');
        }
    };

    // Custom overide for sure
    contactform.init({
        effect: 'fadeToggle',
        speed: 300
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you always operate on someglobal, which is the list of all the modals in the DOM. Instead you should only operate on the modal you choose by the data-target and use the modal's id.

The other thing you might consider is to refactor your plugin a littlebit. Usually you get a selector as the parameter, then you do a loop over all the elements that are being selected by that selector. Something like:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.yourmodal=function(selector,options){
        this.each(function(i, target){
            // and here you do your job for target
        });
    }
})();
```

in your case this way you would add something like this to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.yourmodal(".modal");
});
```

and your plugin will be much more general, reusable.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but can u show me a demo so i can understand it better.

Comment: http://neswork.com/jquery/ball/ and http://neswork.com/jquery/ball/jquery.ball.js and in action: http://neswork.com/flickr/rollr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give unique Class name to model div.
HTML

```
<div id="contactme" data-width="400" data-toggle="modal" class="modal1">
...

<div id="contactyou" data-width="400" data-toggle="modal" class="modal2">
...
```

And In Javascript Pass your require modal class on

```
 var someglobal = $('.modal1'); // or model2
```